# Only one row is posting to server through JSON

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am trying to send data from sqlite to server as json object. It is capturing the data but only one data(row) is going to server.

My json code is

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();


 if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            jobj.put("add_fld1", "Test1");
            jobj.put("add_fld2", "Test2");
            jobj.put("add_fld3", "Test3");

            jobj.put("credated_dt", c.getString(6));
            // jobj.put("id", c.getInt(0));

            jobj.put("emp_code", c.getString(5));
            jobj.put("location", c.getString(3));

            jobj.put("name", c.getString(1));

            jobj.put("phone", c.getString(2));
            jobj.put("remarrks", c.getString(4));

        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
    }

         return jobj.toString();
    }
```

### Update

JsonArray is working but the server is not showing the data now.

JsonArray code

```
    private String getQuery() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, JSONException {

    Cursor c = sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM DETAILS");
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        while (c.moveToNext()) {


            jobj.put("add_fld1", "Test1");
            jobj.put("add_fld2", "Test2");
            jobj.put("add_fld3", "Test3");

            jobj.put("credated_dt", c.getString(6));
            // jobj.put("id", c.getInt(0));

            jobj.put("emp_code", c.getString(5));
            jobj.put("location", c.getString(3));

            jobj.put("name", c.getString(1));

            jobj.put("phone", c.getString(2));
            jobj.put("remarrks", c.getString(4));
            jsonArray.put(jobj);


        }


    return jsonArray.toString();

}
```

Json Array is capturing all the data and response is success but the server is not showing the JsonArray data,but it was showing jsonobject data.

Comment: use Arraylist and add

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya please can you post me the code for JsonArray....because i am very new to android and this json object itself taken me so many days

Comment: In general, if you have a question ban, old questions should not be edited to become new ones. However, this seems to be an update, rather than a completely fresh question, so I think it is OK here. However, you do need to unblock your account with the instructions provided - if you modify your old questions to _completely_ new ones, you can expect downvotes and close votes, which will make your problem worse.

Comment: @halfer its not completely a question ban my attempts for asking questions is over,it is stating that take 3 days time to ask another question and thanks for those words i will take them as advise for future questions.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Yes, if you are being rate-limited, it is best to stick to that advice. The limit will reduce if you ask questions that are well-received. If you have any deleted questions, it can help to improve those and undelete them (but some questions can be unsalvageable, so it's a matter of judgement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Converting the JSONArray again to JSONObject and sending them in one by one solved my problem

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
 boolean flag = false;


        try {
            URL url = new URL();
            JSONArray ja = getQuery();
            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
                bufferedWriter.write(jj.toString());
                Log.e("posted", "" + jj);
                Log.e("doInBackground", "postDataParams");
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                int statusCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                Log.d("this", " The status code is " + statusCode);
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                    flag =true;
                }
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("streams1", "The response is " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } finally {
          Log.e("Delete", "Going to delete");
          sqLiteHelper.deleteAll();
        }
        if(flag)
                return "success";
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a arraylist and put all data in it and send data to server

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();

ArrayList<JSONObject> arrayList=new ArrayList();
 if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            jobj.put("add_fld1", "Test1");
            jobj.put("add_fld2", "Test2");
            jobj.put("add_fld3", "Test3");

            jobj.put("credated_dt", c.getString(6));
            // jobj.put("id", c.getInt(0));

            jobj.put("emp_code", c.getString(5));
            jobj.put("location", c.getString(3));

            jobj.put("name", c.getString(1));

            jobj.put("phone", c.getString(2));
            jobj.put("remarrks", c.getString(4));
           arrayList.add(jobj);
        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
    }

         return arrayList;
    }
```

now you can get all records from this arraylist.
its help me, Please check it.

Comment: It is sending the same data two times Like if i had given x1,x2 it is sending x2 two times

Comment: yeah it is correct @mayank garg the answer posted by Munir is working fine  instead of calling Arraylist he directly used JSONARRAY

Answer (score 0):

You should make a JSONArray and put all data in it and send data to server

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            JSONObject jobj= new JSONObject();
            jobj.put("add_fld1", "Test1");
            jobj.put("add_fld2", "Test2");
            jobj.put("add_fld3", "Test3");

            jobj.put("credated_dt", c.getString(6));
            // jobj.put("id", c.getInt(0));

            jobj.put("emp_code", c.getString(5));
            jobj.put("location", c.getString(3));

            jobj.put("name", c.getString(1));

            jobj.put("phone", c.getString(2));
            jobj.put("remarrks", c.getString(4));
            jsonArray.put(jobj);

        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return jsonArray.toString();
}
```

Comment: Happy to helped you..#

Comment: bro can you help me in one more thing

Comment: @Srivatsav you need to change code in server side.android side done now need to change in server side which handle jsonArray req and save in db

Comment: well then it is designed to accept one value at a time i think..can't we run this  json object like loop??
If i use json array i am getting this The response is Value "Success" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject